# You can use Compute Engine after a project owner enables billing

Tags: google-compute-engine

This is my first question for GCE on StackOverflow.

I've been using GCE for quite some time. I have 4 projects. Suddenly last night I was unable to connect or see VMs in the dashboard. I see a message saying:

You can use Compute Engine after a project owner enables billing.

You do not have permission to enable billing for this project. Contact a project owner to enable billing.

Why is this happening with only 2 projects and not with others? As far as I know payment settings are the same for all 4 projects.

Can you please help me out with this? I'm badly stuck.

Thanks in advance, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLLYj.png) is a picture of my problem.

Comment: As far as I know billing is defined per project, so each project would have different billing. Who is administering these project? Ask them to double check.

Comment: Hi Grzenio,          thanks for your reply. Ok i'll accept what you say my doubt is why did this happen suddenly ? is it because of non payment or something ? i just want to know the root cause. I already informed the guy who maintains billing for all gce accounts. Let's see why he has to say.

Comment: It is impossible to say without checking...

Answer (score 1):

You can have multiple billing accounts, and multiple projects can share a billing account. It sounds like you are not a project owner, so it's possible that a project owner has changed or disabled the billing account for some of the projects you have accessed without your knowledge (or that perhaps there was indeed a problem with the payment method).

When a project cannot be billed, the registered project owners will receive several email notices informing them that there is a problem, and providing information on how to fix it.

In this case it sounds like you are doing the correct action - that is to work with the guy who is the project owner to find out what notices he received, and to make sure a valid billing account is attached to the projects, or followup with billing support if there is an issue that they have notified you about.